# removeClass Not working on dynamically Created CheckBox on GoogleMap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, checkbox

I showed 5 markers on google map with `infowindow`. Each contents has checkbox.
I am adding div contents to Compare list when user click on each.There is `Remove` button to remove them back.I want to UnCheck it on remove.Complete code is here [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z0Lkbmyh/1/)

I have two issues now

1. On Each check i want to keep their ids in hidden fields,I tried this code which is not working

   ```
          var value = [];
           var count = 0;
           $('#map-canvas input:checked').each(function() {
               value+=$(this).attr('value')+',';
               count++;
           });
           $('#cmpIds').val(value);
   ```
2. On Remove button click I want to uncheck each checkbox and hide it.I have this function which is not working for each popup  `onclick="removeAdd(this);"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main issues with your code. Firstly, you are constructing an array incorrectly. In order to construct an array based on the checkbox value, you do not construct it literally (i.e. by inserting `,` between values). Instead, you use `.push()`, i.e.:

```
var value = [],
    count = 0;

$('#map-canvas input:checked').each(function() {
    value.push($(this).attr('value'));
    count++;
});
$('#cmpIds').val(value);
```

---

Secondly, you should also avoid using inline JS for the delete function. Use `.on()` if you want to bind event handlers to dynamically added elements. Therefore, for the injected markup, simply remove the inline JS reference:

```
<a class="text-success">Remove</a>
```

Also, I have used `$(this).closest('.media')` to find the `.parent().parent()`, as it is more verbose. You can cache this selector so jQuery wouldn't have to comb through the DOM repeatedly within the same click event:

```
$(document).on('click', '.text-success', function() {
    var $parent = $(this).closest('.media');

    // Remove listing
    $parent.remove();

    // Uncheck associated textbox
    var parentID = $parent.attr('id'),
        checkboxID = parentID.split('_');

    $('#'+checkboxID).prop('checked', false);
});
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/z0Lkbmyh/4/

---

Additional notes: your `value` array and `count` variable are **reset every time a change event is registered on your checkbox**. I suspect, although I cannot confirm, that this is not the desired behavior — I believe you want to keep track of checked properties on the go. Therefore, you should declare both of them **outside** the `.change()` handler:

```
var value = [],
    count = 0;

$(document).on('change', '.wrapmap-gist input:checkbox', function() {

    $('#map-canvas input:checked').each(function() {
        value.push($(this).attr('value'));
        count++;
    });
    $('#cmpIds').val(value);

    // Rest of your code here

});
```

Comment: Sir,your Remove link is not working...i want to uncheck when some one click remove link

Comment: You might have seen the outdated fiddle. Check this one: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/z0Lkbmyh/4/

Comment: @user3913117 There is one missing piece of logic (you didn't mention it so I'm not sure if you want), is to remove the IDs from the array when a property is unchecked.

Comment: Yes we need to remove also...I supposed it should work:)

Comment: Alright. You should know that since each infobox is dynamic, the checked state is lost when you close it (unless you allow multiple infobox to be open at any one time). Therefore, there is actually no need to loop through all checked checkboxes during `.change()` :) Also, `</ br>` is not valid HTML. It should be `<br />`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '#button-id', function() {
    // your code here
});
```

Comment: I check it but not working...also my first point is not yet fixed